# How can I burn in .ass file and a watermark to a video file using ffmpeg simultaneously?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, watermark

I want to add subtitles and a watermark to a video using ffmpeg. For now, I'm using Handbrake to burn in the subtitles and later I execute an ffmpeg command to add a watermark from png file.

The watermark command:

```
ffmpeg -i F:\ffmpeg\bin\video.mp4 -i F:\ffmpeg\bin\logo.png -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.4[logo];[logo][0]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih*0.07[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)-10:10" output.mp4
```

I was wondering what a command would look like if I wanted to skip the Handbrake part and burn the subtitles in, directly in the same command as the watermark.

I understand the basics of ffmpeg commands and I tried to combine the commands but I got lost. I think the third input would be needed that somehow also goes in the overlay filter. I really hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a big deal, you just have to add the subtitle filter:

```
ffmpeg -i F:\ffmpeg\bin\video.mp4 -i F:\ffmpeg\bin\logo.png -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.4[logo];[logo][0]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih*0.07[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)-10:10[EndVideo];[EndVideo]subtitles=subtitle.ass[EndVideo]" -map [EndVideo] output.mp4
```

Comment: Hi, when I run this command I get an error message saying "No option name near subtitle.ass". I have the subtitle file placed in the same folder as the video and png file and I run the command there.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually subtitles= not subtitle=

Comment: thanks, it worked, for anyone that might be searching for this in the future you might want to map audio from the first input at the end if you get the video without it